# Why is Ubuntu for WSL2 showing up as two separate apps?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl-2, windows-11

I followed a simple list of instructions to get Ubuntu 22.04 setup in WSL2:

1. Run Powershell as Administrator.
2. Type `wsl --install`
3. Reboot PC
4. Open Microsoft Store
5. Install Ubuntu 22.04 https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9PN20MSR04DW
6. Run Ubuntu 22.04

But now I seem to have two installations of Ubuntu:
[image: Apps -> Installed apps showing Ubuntu and Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS]

I've used the "Ubuntu" instance to install my apps so can I uninstall the second one? Or are they both required?

Comment: I don't know, but I can tell you that I uninstalled the one that's just labeled "Ubuntu" (without the version number), and it seems to still work ok (and my ~ files are still there).

But my other question is why I see two apps labeled "Windows Subsystem for Linux", one with a version # and one without.  When I tried removing the one without a version number, my terminal running bash stopped working.  I re-installed, and got the two apps again.